# Perl script to compare two files and report new entries in file 1

Tags: perl

I am looking to compare two files. Incoming file from a vendor with IPs and a local file we have been using that will soon be updated with the vendor copy. I would like it it print only the new data that it finds that is not in our copy.

**IPV4-vendorlist.txt**

```
10.0.0.0
192.168.1.1
192.168.2.2
192.168.3.3
```

**IPV4-outgoing.txt**

```
10.0.0.0
192.168.1.1
192.168.2.2
```

In this example, I would like it to print "The following will be added: 192.168.3.3".

Here is the code I have thus far that runs, it just doesn't produce any output:

```
use strict;

my $fname = 'IPV4-vendorlist.txt';

open my $vendor, "<", $fname
or die "Couldn't open $fname: $!";

my %urls;

while (my $url = <$vendor>) {
  chomp $url;
  $urls{$url} = undef;
}

close $vendor;
$fname = 'IPV4-outgoing.txt';

open my $ourfile, "<", $fname
or die "Couldn't open $fname: $!";

while (my $url = <$ourfile>) {
  chomp $url;
  next if exists $urls{$url}; 
  print "The following will be added: $url";
}

close $ourfile;
```

Comment: maybe you should look for diff tools/libraries

Comment: I agree with @Leo.  I recommend Beyond Compare since the scripting ability is pretty powerful.  You can use it in combination with Perl to do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of thing is trivial to do with [List::Compare](https://metacpan.org/pod/List%3a%3aCompare). Read each file into an array, where each line is an element in the array.  Then:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use List::Compare;
$lc = List::Compare->new(\@vendor_list, \@outgoing);
my @new_ips = $lc->get_unique();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your script (probably) works. There are no IPs in the "outgoing" list which are not also already on the "vendor" list. (Perhaps you meant the other way around? There are addresses on the "vendor" list which are not on the "outgoing" list.)

For what it's worth, standard Unix tools like `diff` and `cmp` and `comm` already provide basic functionality for comparing lists.

Comment: So I did get this working, It was an issue with the source file. Thanks for your help. On a side note, how could I add a line to ignore line one of the source file? The very top line contains "type=ips" which i edit out and would not want to take that into account when comparing. Thanks!

Comment: `next if m/regex/;` is a very common and basic Perl idiom for ignoring some inputs. Tangential follow-up questions are better submitted as new question (but this one would have been closed fairly quickly as "did not google first").