# how to send HTML/Plain Text mail in perl

Tags: html, perl, mime

I am new to the perl language , i want to send the content of plain text file and html text in same email. Where i am getting the file content of a text file but my HTML text is not working i.e i am not a bold sentence in my email . can someone explain how can my html tag to work. Below is my full code.
P.S: when i remove the line print MAIL "MIME-Version: 1.0"  my html tag works but text file is not working (does not prints line by line).

```
use MIME::Lite;
my $HOME        ='/apps/stephen/data';
my $FILE        ="$HOME/LOG.txt";
my @HTML        =();


 push(@HTML,"<b>To send the content of a file in email</b><br>\12");
 push(@HTML,`cat $FILE`);

&sendMail;


sub sendMail
{
$sub="TEST";
$from='ABC@ABC.com';
$to='ABC@ABC.com';
open(MAIL, "|/usr/lib/sendmail -t");
        print MAIL "From: $from \12"; print MAIL "To: $to \12";print    MAIL "Cc: $Cc \12";
        print MAIL "Subject: $sub \12";
        print MAIL "MIME-Version: 1.0" ;
        print MAIL "Content-Type: text/html \12";
        print MAIL "Content-Disposition:inline \12";
        print MAIL @HTML;
    close(MAIL);
}
```

Comment: ok i removed the sendmail but it still works like previously.

Comment: Huh?  What did you remove?  You have `use MIME::Lite` but you use no functions from this package; instead, you painstakingly construct a(n incorrect) MIME structure by hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are preparing to `use MIME::Lite` but then you forget it all and try to piece together a MIME structure by hand. That's painful and error-prone even if you know exactly what you are doing; you should definitely use a suitable set of library functions instead, to keep your code simple and readable, and focus on the actual task.

The [`MIME::Lite` documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/MIME-Lite-3.030/lib/MIME/Lite.pm) shows exactly how to do this, right in the second example in the introduction.

Adapted to your stub code,

```
use MIME::Lite;

use strict;   # always
use warnings; # always

### Create a new multipart message:
$msg = MIME::Lite->new(
    From    => 'ABC@ABC.com',
    To      => 'ABC@ABC.com',
    #Cc      => 'some@other.com, some@more.com',
    Subject => 'TEST your blood pressure with some CAPS LOCK torture',
    Type    => 'multipart/mixed'
);

### Add parts (each "attach" has same arguments as "new"):
$msg->attach(
    Type     => 'text/html',
    Data     => join ('\n', '<b>To see the content of a file in email</b><br/>',
             '<strong><blink><a href="cid:LOG.txt">click here</a></blink></strong>')
);
$msg->attach(
    Type     => 'text/plain',
    Path     => '/apps/stephen/data/LOG.txt',
    Filename => 'LOG.txt',
    Disposition => 'attachment'
);
$msg->send();
```

Comment: thanks a lot !! it works i get an attachment and html body.  Now instead of attachment i want the content in the body of my email just below the html text.

Comment: Then send a single HTML part and embed the plain text in a pair of `<pre>`...`</pre>` tags.

Comment: to send an HTML and plain text body in the same email, but only show the appropriate body depending on the mail client, set the type in the new() to 'multipart/alternative' and then add the 'text/plain' body and THEN the 'text/html' body last.

Comment: @user1663987 The order of the MIME parts inside the `multipart/alternative` isn't important.  As discussed in the comments to [Steffen Ulrich's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23924715/874188) (above or below, depending on how you are viewing this page), the user's preferences and the client software's logic dictate what gets shown.

Comment: @tripleee I've run into clients that will always display the text/plain if that is second

Answer (score 1):

This is not really specific to Perl.
If you want to send a mail with alternative representations of the same data you have to use multipart/alternative, i.e.

```
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-type: multipart/alternative; boundary=foobar

--foobar
Content-type: text/plain

Plain text here
--foobar
Content-type: text/html

<p>HTML text here</p>
--foobar--
```

This way the mail program will pick up the best representation. Since it might be hard to construct such mails by hand you should better use modules like [Email:MIME](https://metacpan.org/pod/Email::MIME), [MIME::Lite](https://metacpan.org/pod/MIME::Lite) or [MIME::tools](https://metacpan.org/release/MIME-tools).

> P.S: when i remove the line print MAIL "MIME-Version: 1.0" my html tag works but text file is not working (does not prints line by line).

It's no wonder since you forgot the end of line, i.e. instead of

```
    print MAIL "MIME-Version: 1.0" ;
```

It should be

```
    print MAIL "MIME-Version: 1.0\n" ;
```

Apart from that it is more clear to use `\n` instead of `\12`.

And of you insist of creating the MIME-Message by hand please have a closer look at the related standards, see also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME. Notably there must be an empty line between Mail/Mime header and body and there is no need to add a space to the end of each header line.

Comment: "Best" is usually not correct.  If the mail client only can display text/plain then it will choose text/plain.  If the user has specified that they prefer text/plain, then it will choose text/plain. Many HTML-only mail authors wish it didn't work this way but that's how it works, and that's how it should work.

Comment: "best" is from the perspective of the mail client. If the user requested display of plain over HTML then plain is the best. And yes, many authors and even some mail clients don't handle this case correctly, like sending different content in plain and HTML or adding attachments only to the HTML part (AppleMail).

Comment: We basically agree then.  Maybe also mention that there needs to be an empty line between the headers and body, which is also a failure in the OP's code.

Comment: Also, the intent is apparently to attach a file, although the OP forgot to actually do anything with the text file which is defined near the top of the code.